# Wrong outcome while summing big arrays

Tags: c++

I keep getting wrong outcome, while I try to sum big arrays. I have isolated problem to the following code sample (its not an sum of a big array, but I believe this is The problem)

### Compilable Sample:

```
template <typename T>
void cpu_sum(const unsigned int size, T & od_value) {
    od_value = 0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        od_value += 1;
    }
}

int main() {
    typedef float Data;
    const unsigned int size = 800000000;
    Data sum;
    cpu_sum(size, sum);

    cout << setprecision(35) << sum << endl; // prints: 16777216 // ERROR !!!
    getchar();
}
```

### Environment:

**OS:** Windows 8.1 x64 home 
**IDE:** Microsoft Visual Studio 2015

### Error Description:

While my outcome should obviously be `sum == 800000000` I keep getting `sum == 16777216`. 
That is very weird for me, because float max value is far above this one, and yet it looks like `sum` variable reach its limit.

**What did I miss??**

Comment: It is a well known problem. Gradually your sum becomes so big that next summand becomes comparable with an epsilon (about 10^-14) of it. At that moment you start loosing precision.

Comment: The mystery `sum` is 2^24. The mantissa of a floats is... 24 bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a well known problem. Gradually your sum becomes so big that next summand becomes comparable with an epsilon (about 10^-14) of it. At that moment you start loosing precision.

Standard solution is to change summation tactics: when array larger than, say, 100 elements, split it in halves and sum each half separately. It goes on recursively and tend to keep precision much better.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by [Michael Simbursky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2876861/michael-simbirsky), this is a well-known problem when trying to sum a large number of limited-precision numbers.  The solution he provides works well, and is quite efficient.

For the curious reader, a slower method is to sort your array before computing the sum, assuring that the values are added in order of increasing absolute value.  This ensures that the least-significant values make their contributions to the overall sum before being overwhelmed by the other values.  This technique is used more as an example/illustration than in any serious programming ventures.

For serious scientific programming where the overall size of the data can vary a great deal, another algorithm to be aware of is the [Kahan Summation Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm), and the referenced wikipedia page provides a nice description of it.